# Angular Material 15 -> 16: Styling of checked toggle-button with .mat-button-toggle-checked not working any longer

Tags: angular-material16

After migrating from Angular Material 15 to 16 I encounter this issue:

In my SCSS I have the following entry to set the color of a checked toggle button:

```
.mat-button-toggle-checked {
  color: $white;
}
```

This worked fine with Material 15, after upgrading to 16 the effective color ist overridden by
var(--mat-standard-button-toggle-selected-state-text-color) with black again.

Workarounds:

1. Use !important -> works, but is bad practice
2. Setting an individual class for the mat-button-toggle and use it in the SCSS -> works, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution. I do not understand why the specific SCSS for my HTML template is not ranked highest in this case.